# In d3 eliminate the SI unit and display only the numeric

Tags: d3.js

In d3 how to display only the numeric value with out the SI letter?. For example display only 12 instead of 12M on the axis.

Comment: you must be using d3.format somewhere in your code remove that.

Comment: This is what i am using, var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));   If I don't use that I get a number on axis like 10,000,000. With what I am doin currently, I get 10M, but I need 10 instead of 10M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you basically want to divide the values in the `y` ticks by 1,000,000. Simply give a "dividing function" to `tickFormat` (which also converts to string, to be on the safe side), like this:

```
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis() .scale(y) .orient("left") 
                .tickFormat(function(n){return n/1000000+""});
```